# How to change the value for the data we set of an input when we leave the page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I don't get how to change the value of an input field in a php foreach,
The value display is contain in a string array,
I want it to change when the user change page not whenever he changes the value of the field.
Any idea how to do that? any help will be welcome!
here is the code

```
foreach ($listeValeur as $value) {
                $i ++;
                ?> 
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input onChange="this.form.submit();" name="leChamp" type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" value="<?php echo $value;?>">
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"> 
                            <button class="buttonNoStyle" type="submit" name="supprimerLeChoix"><i class="pointer colorIconDeleteLight iconSize fas fa-times" title="Supprimer le choix"></i></button>
                            <button class="buttonNoStyle" type="submit" name="supprimerTout"><i class="pointer colorIconDeleteStrong iconSize secondIconPadding fas fa-trash-alt" title="Tout supprimer"></i></button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
            <?php
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the the form to be submitted as soon as the user types in the box, then you should remove the "onChange" event from the textbox.

Then the user will need to press the submit button before the data will be sent to the server.

i.e. remove this:

```
onChange="this.form.submit();"
```

If you weren't sure what this code was doing, please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Comment: I did it for a test and actually it is closer from what i want "a no button" change

Comment: Ok. It's unclear what you really want then. You can't send data to the server without some sort of event occurring. Either the use must explicitly press a button, or you must detect some event in the page. The "change" event of the textbox would actually be a sensible one, because that tells you that the user has finished typing in the box, and that there is likely to be some data worth sending. if you don't want either of those things, then you're going to have to make it clearer what you _do_ want, because it doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: P.S. You say you want this "when the user change page"...but that's backwards. The act of submitting the data is the thing which makes the page change! The page doesn't change unless the user submits the form. (Unless of course they click on another link or press the back button...but you can't worry about that - any user who has used the web for more than 5 minutes will understand that those are actions which won't cause their data to be submitted.)